# How do I get the size of the boost buffer

Tags: c++, boost, arrays, buffer, boost-asio

I am trying to make an asynchronised server in visual studio and I use

```
boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer), 
                        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

to get the buffer to be put in m_buffer

```
boost::array<char, 256> m_buffer;
```

but how do I get the size of this thing, m_buffer?

size() didn't work, end() didn't work.. Any help would be fantastic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `size()` didn't work?

Comment: I tried cout.write(m_buffer.data(),m_buffer.size()); but it outputted the whole thing. It was just one char, so I would like it to output just that one char. Or at least store the length.

Comment: It makes sense that it printed the whole buffer, because you've specified the size of whole buffer as the number of characters to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::array` has a constant size. If you want to print it as a null-terminated string, use [`.data()` to get a `const char*`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/array.html#id415260-bb).

If you just want to find the position of the `\0`, [use `std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

```
int size = find(array.begin(), array.end(), '\0') - array.begin();
```

Comment: std::cout.write(m_buffer.data(), std::find(m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.end(), '\0') - m_buffer.begin()); 
still doesn't seem to output anything.

Comment: @Anonymous: Maybe the m_buffer is empty? Try to print `std::find(m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.end(), '\0') - m_buffer.begin()`.

Comment: @Anon: It cannot "print nothing". Are you using `cout <<`?

Comment: std::cout << "We are reading: ";
   std::cout << find(m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.end(), '\0') - m_buffer.begin();

All I see is the first one.

Comment: @anon: `cout << (find(...) - m_buffer.begin());`

Answer (score 0):

boost::arrays have constant size based on the second template argument. You can retrieve their size by calling their size() method. See [boost::array documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/array.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you specified the size of the buffer to be 256, and then you place a character at location `0` in the buffer and try to `cout` the buffer, it will print the entire buffer.  This is because the program has no way of knowing that you placed only one "valid" character in the buffer.  You will need to keep a separate "pointer" into the buffer yourself that lets you know where your data ends and the "empty" part of the buffer begins.